# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Even after adding certificate

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c, sslhandshakeexception

I am using weblogic server which has keystores in use like :

[image]

Now when my application running on this server tries to download images from another server, it throws
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`

I have added server certificates to these both `DemoTrust.jks` and `JDK CACERTS` using [this link](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2016/07/wls-how-to-import-ssl-cert-into-wls.html) :
after adding certificates, it looks like :

[image]

And java certs has

[image]

As suggested by different posts, I have also added to startWeblogic.cmd

> set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true
> set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enable.renegotiation=true
> set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true

Am I missing something ? Any Suggestions ?

Edit 1 : Adding exception stacktrace

> vax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1529)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
> at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$1.run(JaSSLEngine.java:69)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:743)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.wrap(JaSSLEngine.java:67)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.wrapAndWrite(JSSEFilterImpl.java:771)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:119)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:87)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:250)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:577)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:557)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:265)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:651)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
> at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
> at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
> at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor235.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254.execute(Unknown Source)
> at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
> at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:330)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:992)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:989)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1467)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:223)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:123)
> ... 44 more
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)
> at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:999)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1601)
> ... 52 more
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
> ... 60 more

Comment: Sha1 keys are different may be because they were exported and added on different dates. But when tried to add again, it gives me error, it already exists.

Comment: To add : It worked up yesterday post importing certificates, but post restarting laptop and weblogic server, I am facing this issue

Comment: Let's try to understand what is actually happening during the handshake proces. For that we need the logs of it. Could you start your server with the following parameters: `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake` and share the full logs including the part when the request has been executed to the other server?

Comment: @Hakan54 added stacktrace

Comment: A bit late from my side. I have the feeling that the ssl configuration you have provided is only being used for the server. However the server is executing a https request to another server with a http client. I don't think that http client within the server has a ssl configuration present. Can you maybe share how the external request is being constructed and executed?

Answer (score -1):

Hello to whoever still looking for an answer,

Hope this helps you.

I also had similar issue in running my application in Jdeveloper 12.2.1.4.0.

Let me explain my situation and solution.

My application in Jdeveloper calls a REST api running in remote server.
I downloaded the cert from browser by loading the remote server URL. I uploaded to Demotrust.jks file in oracle middleware folder.
While running the application, I can see remote server cert appearing in Jdev logs (after turning on ssl debugging), but still the application was facing `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine error` while calling remote server REST api. I verified that the certificate is not expired.

In Weblogic admin console, I turned off `Use KSS demo` flag (Under `Domain -> Security -> Advanced`).

I have also set `Hostname verification` to `None` in SSL because its a wildcard certificate `(Servers -> DefaultServer -> SSL -> advanced)`. Still getting the SSLEngine problem. I found one more thing that needs to be set correctly.

The remote server is running within corp network.
I found that **proxy** in Jdeveloper preferences is set to automatic. I set it to **None** (ofcourse test connection will fail and its ok) and restarted the server. With all of these configuration in place, the application is able to connect to REST API.